# How to filter dataframes based on criteria in a tibble?

Tags: r

I have recreated my problem using the diamonds dataset from ggplot2 in R.

I would like to create a list (`my_list`), where each element in that list is the `diamond` dataframe that has has been filtered by specific criteria, laid out in a tibble (`analys`).

So for example:

`my_list[[1]]` would have the dataframe `diamonds`, but only including diamonds where the `colour` is equal to `E` or `J`.  `my_list[[2]]` would have the dataframe `diamonds`, but only including diamonds where the `clarity` is equal to `SI2` or `VS1`. `my_list[[3]]` would have the dataframe `diamonds`, but only including diamonds where the `cut` is equal to `Good` or `Very Good`.

```
library(ggplot2)
diamonds = as.data.frame(diamonds)

# create a tibble with the list of filters I want
# eg, row 1 would mean I want only diamonds that have either the colour E or J.

analys <- tribble(
    ~column,   ~trt,   ~ctrl,       ~translation,
    "color",   "E",    "J",         "E vs J",
    "clarity", "SI2",  "VS1",       "SI1 vs VS1",
    "cut",     "Good", "Very Good", "Good vs Very Good")

# next create an empty list to populate
my_list = list()

# now create a function to filter diamonds dataframe, keeping only the entries where,
# for example the colour would be E or J (specified in the analys tibble).
my_list <- apply(analys, 1, function(x) subset(
    diamonds,
    x[["column"]] %in% c(x[["trt"]], x[["ctrl"]])
    )
)
```

However, the above function does not appear to work when using x[["column"]].  Can someone please correct this function so that it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way using some non-standard evaluation :

```
library(dplyr)

apply_fun <- function(data, col, value1, value2) {
   data %>% filter(!!sym(col) %in% c(value1, value2))
}

temp <- apply(analys, 1, function(x) 
              apply_fun(diamonds, x[['column']], x[['trt']], x[['ctrl']]))
```

`head` of each list looks like :

```
lapply(temp, head)
#[[1]]
#  carat       cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
#1  0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326 3.95 3.98 2.43
#2  0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326 3.89 3.84 2.31
#3  0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327 4.05 4.07 2.31
#4  0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335 4.34 4.35 2.75
#5  0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336 3.94 3.96 2.48
#6  0.22      Fair     E     VS2  65.1    61   337 3.87 3.78 2.49

#[[2]]
#  carat       cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
#1  0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326 3.95 3.98 2.43
#2  0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327 4.05 4.07 2.31
#3  0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335 4.34 4.35 2.75
#4  0.23 Very Good     H     VS1  59.4    61   338 4.00 4.05 2.39
#5  0.23     Ideal     J     VS1  62.8    56   340 3.93 3.90 2.46
#6  0.31     Ideal     J     SI2  62.2    54   344 4.35 4.37 2.71

#[[3]]
#  carat       cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
#1  0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327 4.05 4.07 2.31
#2  0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335 4.34 4.35 2.75
#3  0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336 3.94 3.96 2.48
#4  0.24 Very Good     I    VVS1  62.3    57   336 3.95 3.98 2.47
#5  0.26 Very Good     H     SI1  61.9    55   337 4.07 4.11 2.53
#6  0.23 Very Good     H     VS1  59.4    61   338 4.00 4.05 2.39
```

---

If you want to stay in `tidyverse`, you can use `pmap` which will add the list column in `analys` dataframe itself.

```
analys %>%
  mutate(temp = purrr::pmap(list(column, trt, ctrl), 
                  ~apply_fun(diamonds, ..1, ..2, ..3)))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  column  trt   ctrl      translation       temp                   
#  <chr>   <chr> <chr>     <chr>             <list>                 
#1 color   E     J         E vs J            <df[,10] [12,605 × 10]>
#2 clarity SI2   VS1       SI1 vs VS1        <df[,10] [17,365 × 10]>
#3 cut     Good  Very Good Good vs Very Good <df[,10] [16,988 × 10]>
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Ronak you have multiple options to make this work. Essentially, you need to have `x[["column"]]` be treated as a symbol.

Here is another way to make this work using your function. You can build your expression as a string separately with `parse_expr`, and then use `eval` in `subset`:

```
my_list <- apply(analys, 1, function(x) {
  ex <- parse_expr(paste0(x[["column"]], "%in% c('", x[["trt"]], "','", x[["ctrl"]], "')"))
  subset(diamonds, eval(ex))
})
```